# Remove() images after success on multiple file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I'm trying to get all my preview images to .remove() on success and wondering how i would do so.

***Whats happening -***
If say I uploaded two images.. only one of the two images would remove() on success; if I upload three images then images, two previews of the three remain. So its only removing one preview image. which I believe is the last inserted preview image.

here is what I' have.

```
 //functions on change event of file input to select different file 
    $('body').on('change', '#image_data', function(){
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                     abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

                    var z = abc - 1;
                    var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                    $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                    }));
                }
            });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
```

Success

```
success: function(data)   
{
$("#previewimg" + abc).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are removing by Ids all are not getting removed at once.
If you want to remove all images at once, you can use a class instead of Ids.

```
 //functions on change event of file input to select different file 
$('body').on('change', '#image_data', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                 abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

                var z = abc - 1;
                var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
                $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src='' class='previewImages'/></div>");

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                }));
            }
        });

//To preview image     
    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
       $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

On success:

```
success: function(data)   
{
     $(".previewImages").remove();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Did the trick for me. Why I racked my brains so much over something so simple. Thank you for your help/ Much appreciated.

Comment: :) Awesome!  Happy it helped!

Comment: I'll be sure to accept the answer as soon as I can  Thanks again